# How are the coefficients of the Region of Interest being selected?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers

I was reading the following paper: [Rl-Ncs: Reinforcement Learning Based Data-Driven Approach For Nonuniform Compressed Sensing](http://cwnlab.eecs.ucf.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2019_MLSP_ANCS_NAZMUL.pdf), and my question is: how do they decide whether a signal is characterized as a region of interest coefficient or non-region of interest coefficient?